# Create dynamic LINQ expression for Select with FirstOrDefault inside

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to write this groupQuery:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TEntity>> groupQuery;
...
IQueryable<TEntity> query2 = groupQuery.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

as dynamically expression:

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");

IQueryable<TEntity> query2 = groupQuery.Provider.CreateQuery(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Select",
        new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), typeof(TKey)},
        groupQuery.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda(firstOrDefaultExpression, param)));
```

How to write firstOrDefaultExpression and how to complete this dynamically expression for same result as `groupQuery.Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it :

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> SelectFirst<TEntity,TKey>(IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TEntity>> groupQuery)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(groupQuery.ElementType, "x");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IGrouping<TKey, TEntity>,TEntity>>(
            Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),"FirstOrDefault",new []{typeof(TEntity)},param), 
            param);

        var select = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Select",
            new []{groupQuery.ElementType,typeof(TEntity)},
            groupQuery.Expression,lambda);
        return groupQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(select);
    }
```

And then you call that as :

```
SelectFirst(list.GroupBy(x=>[...]).AsQueryable());
```

Comment: Thanks. Works with some modifications.