# Creating a LINQ Select expression dynamically from string column names

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a method which looks something like this:

```
public string GetColVal(string aAcctField, bool callM1, bool callM2)
{
    if (callM1)
    {
        // create select clause here to select a string column with name
        // equal to the value of aAcctField from Table1
        // Expression<Func<Table1, string>> selector = ?
        return M1(selector);
    }

    if (callM2)
    {
        // create select clause here to select a string column with name
        // equal to the value of aAcctField from Table2
        // Expression<Func<Table2, string>> selector = ?
        return M2(selector);
    }
}
```

And `M1()` is something like this:

```
public string M1(Expression<Func<Table1, string>> columnToSelect, string xType)
{
    // other logic 
    string acct = _cntx.Where(c => c.Type == xType)
                       .Select(columnToSelect)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
    return acct;
}
```

`M2()` is also something similar. Please note that the methods are over-simplified. And the methods `M1()` and `M2()` work perfectly. I can invoke them this way:

```
// MyColumn is a strongly typed column in Table1
string acct = M1(x => x.MyColumn, "some value");
```

---

But, inside the method `GetColVal()` how do I construct the select clauses? The comments regarding `selector` will help you understand what I intend to do. So, please go ahead and read the comment.

I have tried this:

```
public string GetColVal(string aAcctField, bool callM1, bool callM2)
{
    if (callM1)
    {
        // create select clause here to select a string column with name
        // equal to the value of aAcctField from Table1
        Expression<Func<Table1, string>> selector = (w) => w.GetType().GetProperty(aAcctField).Name;
        return M1(selector);
    }
    ...
}
```

and I get the exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(System.String)' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

I have looked at these:

- [Create dynamic LINQ expression for Select with FirstOrDefault inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922214/create-dynamic-linq-expression-for-select-with-firstordefault-inside)
- [Linq access property by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770897/linq-access-property-by-variable)
- [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)
- and many others.

but none of them is quite something like what I need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically you need to use the [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) class methods like [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Expression.PropertyOrField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.propertyorfield(v=vs.110).aspx) etc. to build the desired selector like:

```
static Expression<Func<T, TValue>> MemberSelector<T, TValue>(string name)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TValue>>(body, parameter);
}
```

To support nested properties, change `var body = ...` line to

```
var body = name.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
```

Sample usage:

```
if (callM1)
{
    return M1(MemberSelector<Table1, string>(aAcctField));
}
...
```

Comment: Is `MemberSelector` an extension method? If not (and I think it is not), what is it, and where do I place it? Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: No problem. You could put it inside the same class where you need to call it. Or in a separate static class, like inside `public static class ExpressionUtils` (add `public` modifier to the method) and use `ExpressionUtils.MemberSelector` or if you are on C#6, put `using static SomeNamespace.ExpressionUtils;` and continue call it simply as `MemberSelector`.

Comment: Works awesomely! I will have to spend some time on it though, in order to assimilate the whole of it :-)